# Showing that this defines an equivalent norm on a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $(E,\|\cdot\|)$ be a Banach space. Let $N:E\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by: $$N(x)=\sup\{|\varphi(x)|: \,\varphi:E\to R,\, \text{linear and} \|\varphi\|_{E^{\prime}}=1\}$$ where $E^{\prime}$ is a topological dual space of $E$.

My goal is to show that $N$ is a norm on $E$ equivalent to the initial norm of $E$. I don't know if this fact is true. Thanks.

Comment: Very seldom are three questions marks justified.

Comment: For the ordinary dual space Hahn-Banach tells you that $N(x) = \| x\|$. What exactly do you mean by "a topological dual space"?

Comment: topological dual space for me is the space of all linear real-valued continuous map on E. I don't see why by Hahn-Banach we have $N(x)=\|x\|$. Thank for your help.

Comment: In that case you should work through martini's outline :-)

Comment: People keep down voting without understanding, but it is not something new on this website. The OP woundering about the equivalence of norms and I provide him the answer " In finite dimensional spaces, norms are equivalent".

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: I'm pretty sure people perfectly understood that your hint provided an answer in a trivial special case. They also understood that it is completely useless for answering the general case, so it does certainly not provide a "hint" and as such it is "not useful" as others already pointed out.

Comment: @Martin: Just do not make a big fuss of it. The OP was wondering about the equivalence of the norms and I gave him the answer and I do not see it is wrong.

Comment: @Martin: You speak for the down voters. What for?

Comment: @Martin: If they see it is not useful, it is only their opinion but it is not a judgement. I hope you understand this.

Comment: @Mhenni: You didn't give "*the answer*", because the question asks about any Banach space $E$, not just the finite-dimensional ones. You didn't even give a *hint*, seeing as how your answer ***cannot possibly help*** to solve the problem in the case when $E$ is not finite-dimensional. That is why many people think your answer was not useful, and downvoted it (which is exactly what they are supposed to do - that is how the site works).

Comment: @ZevChonoles: I gave a hint related to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Let $x \in X - \{0\}$ and $E_x := \mathbb K\cdot x$ denote the one-dimensional subspace generated by  Define a functional $\phi \colon E_x \to \mathbb K$ by $\phi(\lambda x) = \lambda \def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}\norm x$. Then $\phi \in E_x'$ with $\norm{\phi}_{E_x'} = 1$ (Can you see why?). Choose an Hahn-Banach extension $\psi \in E'$ with $\psi|_{E_x} = \phi$ and $\norm{\psi} = \norm{\phi}$. What is $|\psi(x)|$? What does this tell you about $N(x)$?

Comment: @Serges: I noticed that you never accepted an answer to any of your questions so far. Please consider doing so in order to indicate to others that the questions have been answered to your satisfaction. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for instructions how to do it.

Comment: @martini: I really don't clearly see the relation between $|\psi(x)|$ and $N(x)$. Thank to be more precise